$4^n$ is not a sum of four distinct squares
The famous theorem of Lagrange tells us that any natural number can be written as a sum of four squares, where the summands are not necessarily distinct. After some experiments, I have concluded that $4^n$ cannot be written as a sum of four distinct squares.
Is it true? If yes, then how can we prove it? I have tried using modular arithmetic, but it did not work very well. Let's assume that $4^n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, where $n\geq 1$. If we consider both sides $\pmod{4}$, then the LHS is $0$, but the RHS is $0,1,2,3 \pmod{4}$ because $i^2\equiv 0,1 \pmod{4}$. However, this observation does not yield any result.
Can anyone show how to prove it, please?
UPD. I know we can apply Jacobi's theorem to this problem, and I thought about it before creating the post. But I am wondering, can we solve it more easily? My goal is to explain this to an undergraduate student who is not familiar with Jacobi's result and I think Jacobi's result is not a trivial result.

Note:  I assume that you are asking about sums of distinct squares, and my posted solution addresses that for powers of $2$ (you don't need powers of $4$).  To be sure:  this notion of "distinct" would consider $(-a)^2$ and $a^2$ to be the same, though Jacobi would consider them as different.

@JMoravitz, yeah I am asking about the sum of 4 distinct squares and I have mentioned it in my post.

@JMoravitz Please, read carefully the post.

First, note that $4$ cannot be written as sum of distinct squares.
It is enough to show that if $N$ is even, then any representation of $4N$ as sum of four squares must involve only even squares. Because then, we can use an induction argument.
To do that, we only need to recall that odd squares are $1\pmod 8$.

Good argument (+1). For $2^n$  we can do the same,  just need two base cases.

Thanks for your answer! I haven't read it in detail yet, but I have a few questions: 1) Are you proving by induction? 2) Are you proving the statement for $4^N$ or $4N$? Because I see $4N$ in your argument.

@CalvinLin you're right! I changed the claim. Afterall the base cases of the Induction argument are $2$ and $4$ !

@RFZ I am using $4N$ - the observation that drives this argument is that the representations of $N$ and $4N$ are basically the same (i.e., multiplied by $2$)

Got it! Nice induction argument! +1

Indeed, $2^n$ can't be written as the sum of four distinct squares.
Pf:
Jacobi's $4-$square Theorem tells us that that there are exactly $24$ distinct ways to express $2^n$ as a sum of $4$ squares (N.B. "distinct", in this context, allows both order and sign changes.).
But, suppose $2^n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ with all squares distinct.  Then, if all squares were non-zero,  there would be at least $16\times 4!$ ways to write $2^n$ as a sum of $4$ squares, which would contradict Jacobi.  Even if one of the squares was allowed to be $0$, but all $4$ still assumed to be distinct, we'd have at least $8\times 4!$ solutions, still well above the Jacobi limit.

Hey! First of all, your link is broken. Is there an easy way to do this? I think Jacobi's theorem might be a bit overkill.

The link works fine for me.....

I've repaired the link, sorry about that.  maybe for $4^n$ there is a shorter proof?  I didn't think about it.  Don't think there is a significantly easier proof for $2^n$ (though of course I might be wrong about that).

Just a small remark regarding your third paragraph: You said that there would be at least $16 \times 4!$ representations, but I believe this is true only if all $a, b, c, d$ are non-zero. If one of them is zero, then it should be at least $2^3 \times 4!$. Anyway, it contradicts Jacobi.

@RFZ  Agreed, I'll edit to include that note.

Claim: Only integer solutions to $4^n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is $a=b=c=d=2^{n-1}$ or $a=b=c=0$ and $d=2^{n}$ up to sign and permutation.
For $n\geq 2$, take the equation $\bmod 8$ to get $0\equiv a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ and noting that quadratic residues $\bmod 8$ are $\{0,1,4\}$ we get that all of $a,b,c,d$ must be even. Thus we can reduce any solution $4^n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ for $n \geq 2$ to $4=A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2$ where $A=a/2^{n-1}$, $B=b/2^{n-1}$.. etc. The equation $4=A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2$ has only solutions $(A,B,C,D):(1,1,1,1)$ or $(A,B,C,D):(2,0,0,0)$ up to permutation and sign. This proves the claim.

This is similar to my solution, only much more sahaj... (+1)

Thank you sir! It is indeed a common technique to look for the parity of the terms to try and make the equation simpler.
